# Importing config with parseconfig in ruby

Tags: ruby, return-value, config

I have a .publicancreators.cfg with that content:

```
# Global
name = Sascha Manns
email_private = Sascha.Manns@bdvb
```

Then i have defined a method:

```
def self.config
    config = ParseConfig.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '.publicancreators.cfg'))
    name = config['name']
    email_private = config['email_private']
    return %w(name email)
end
```

For using that i'm running inside my main program:

```
a, b = PublicanCreatorsGet.config
name = "#{a}"
email = "#{b}"
```

The idea comes from that doku: https://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2011/11/21/return-multiple-values-from-a-ruby-method/

If i'm running that code i'm getting:

```
<class:PublicanCreators>': undefined local variable or method `config' for PublicanCreators:Class (NameError)
```

Maybe anyone can help?

Comment: _Sidenote__ by returning `return %w(name email)` you return _strings_ `"name"` and `"email"`, not their values. `return` keyword is superfluous as well. The very last line should be `[name, email_private]`. The error is induced, it has nothing to do with parsing config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides some code glitches I fixed, I have no problem executing the code:

```
require 'parseconfig'
class A
  def self.config
    config = ParseConfig.new('/tmp/q.cfg')
    name = config['name']
    email_private = config['email_private']
    [name, email_private]
  end 
end

a, b = A.config

puts "name is [#{a}], email is [#{b}]"
#⇒ name is [Sascha Manns], email is [Sascha.Manns@bdvb]
```

Your problem is induced.